# Getting equations from asymptotic expansion

Tags: series-expansion

I want to solve the equation by means of asymptotic expansion. After having defined the equation and the series:

```
eq1 = u[x] == 1 + ϵ u[x]^3;
w[x_, ϵ_] = 1 + ϵ Subscript[u, 1][x] + ϵ^2 Subscript[u, 2][x] + ϵ^3 Subscript[u, 3][x];
eq1exp = eq1 /. u[x] -> w[x, ϵ]
```

I have to get a set of equations for each degree of the small paramater $\varepsilon$. How can I get the list of equations mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

In version M12 you can use the new function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) to do all the work:

```
AsymptoticSolve[u == 1 + ϵ u^3, u, {ϵ, 0, 3}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\left\{u\to 12 \epsilon ^3+3 \epsilon ^2+\epsilon +1\right\},\left\{u\to \frac{105
>    \epsilon ^{3/2}}{128}-\frac{3 \epsilon ^2}{2}-\frac{\epsilon }{2}+\frac{3
>    \sqrt{\epsilon }}{8}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}-\frac{1}{2}\right\},\left\{u\to
>    -\frac{105 \epsilon ^{3/2}}{128}-\frac{3 \epsilon ^2}{2}-\frac{\epsilon }{2}-\frac{3
>    \sqrt{\epsilon }}{8}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}-\frac{1}{2}\right\}\right\}$

**Old answer**

Something like:

```
SolveAlways[Normal @ Series[eq1exp, {ϵ, 0, 3}], ϵ]
```

> {{Subscript[u, 3][x] -> 12, Subscript[u, 2][x] -> 3, Subscript[u, 1][x] -> 1}}

perhaps?

For just the equations you can use one of the following:

```
Thread[Series[eq1exp,{ϵ, 0, 3}][[All, 3]]]
Thread[CoefficientList[#, ϵ]& /@ Series[eq1exp, {ϵ, 0, 3}]]
```

> {True, Subscript[u, 1][x] == 1, Subscript[u, 2][x] == 3 Subscript[u, 1][x], 
>    Subscript[u, 3][x] == 3 (Subscript[u, 1][x]^2 + Subscript[u, 2][x])}
>
> {True, Subscript[u, 1][x] == 1, Subscript[u, 2][x] == 3 Subscript[u, 1][x], 
>    Subscript[u, 3][x] == 3 (Subscript[u, 1][x]^2 + Subscript[u, 2][x])}

Comment: This solution is perfectly suited to this example. But in case of differential equations it seems that a command like DSolveAlways doesn't exists. Could I get just a list of equations I would be able to solve it.

Comment: @ArtemZefirov See update.

Comment: The second variant is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Could you modify your last answer, which I've accepted, in order to make it work with equations like
      `u[x]- ϵ u[x]^3 == 1`
The current command returns "False" because of the right part of the equation has only one coefficient in expansion but not three.

Answer (score 0):

`CoefficientArrays[eq1exp, ϵ]` returns the list of required coefficients.